# How can I avoid read errors when two python scripts access a single pickle file?

Tags: python, pickle

I need to pass data between two Python scripts that are initiated from two different sources. I have seen my logger with a read errors. Is there a better way?

**Program A:** Regularly writes to a pickle file about every minute.

```
def cacheData(filepath, data):
    #create a cPickle file to cache the current data
    try:  
        outFile = open(filepath,'wb')  
        #cPickle the current data to a file  
        cPickle.dump(data, outFile)  
        outFile.close()   
    except Exception, e:  
        logger.warn("Error creating cache file")
```

**Program B:** Is a compiled executable initiated by the user. It reads the pickle file to initiate some code.

```
def readCachedObj(filepath):
    #read cPickle file and return data as object
    try:
        inFile = open(filepath,'rb')
        cache = cPickle.load(inFile)
        inFile.close()
        return cache
    except Exception, e:
        logger.warn("Error reading cached data cPickle")
```

## UPDATE 1

```
def replace(src, dst):
    win32api.MoveFileEx(src, dst, win32con.MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING)    

def cacheData(filepath, data):
    #create a cPickle file to cache the current data
    try:  
        tmpfile = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.tmp'
        outFile = open(tmpfile,'wb')  
        #cPickle the current data to a temp file  
        cPickle.dump(data, outFile)  
        outFile.close()  
        #replace the pickle file with the new temp file
        replace(tmpfile, filepath)    
        #remove any extraneous temp files
        for f in glob.glob("*.tmp"):
            os.remove(f)        
    except Exception, e:  
        logger.warn("Error creating cache file")  

def readCachedObj(filepath):
    #read cPickle file and return data as object
    try:     
        inFile = open(filepath,'rb')
        cache = cPickle.load(inFile)
        inFile.close()
        return cache
    except Exception, e:
        logger.warn("Error reading cached data cPickle")
```

Comment: Maybe... But this is not how you ask here. Do you actually have a problem **now**? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, I've seen errors on the read side. I'm posting my code and have re-formatted it. First time on stack-overflow - thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This seems to do it for me. By creating the new temp file and then using file overwrite, the cacheData function is alot snappier when dealing with the final pickle file.

```
def replace(src, dst):
    win32api.MoveFileEx(src, dst, win32con.MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING)    

def cacheData(filepath, data):
    #create a cPickle file to cache the current data
    try:  
        tmpfile = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.tmp'
        outFile = open(tmpfile,'wb')  
        #cPickle the current data to a temp file  
        cPickle.dump(data, outFile)  
        outFile.close()  
        #replace the pickle file with the new temp file
        replace(tmpfile, filepath)    
        #remove any extraneous temp files
        for f in glob.glob("*.tmp"):
            os.remove(f)        
    except Exception, e:  
        logger.warn("Error creating cache file")  

def readCachedObj(filepath):
    #read cPickle file and return data as object
    try:     
        inFile = open(filepath,'rb')
        cache = cPickle.load(inFile)
        inFile.close()
        return cache
    except Exception, e:
        logger.warn("Error reading cached data cPickle")
```

Answer (score 1):

Never overwrite an existing file. Instead, write to a *new* file, and then perform an (atomic) rename after you successfully close it.

Comment: I've found out Python 2.7 needs Win32 on windows and added to the code above using a temp file as you suggested under UPDATE 1.